# Restore scroll state of nested recyclerview in ConcatAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-concatadapter

I'm using the new [ConcatAdapter](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a) & the Android navigation component to create a complex recyclerView which contains nested horizontal scrollable lists. I'm trying to restore the state of these nested lists on rotation, navigation, etc. I've read [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334) article on the topic, but I'm struggling on how to restore the state in this case.

The `adapter.stateRestorationPolicy = PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY` in the article above, doesn't work when I apply it to my adapter which contains the nested recyclerview. I've tried updating the nested adapters when I receive the data and I've tried adding them to the concat adapter on data receival, but with no succes.

**My Fragment**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
   
    val concatAdapter = ConcatAdapter()

    binding.recyclerView.apply {
        adapter = concatAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    }

    viewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { listItems ->
        concatAdapter.addAdapter(NestedListAdapter(listItems))
    })
}
```

Also tried this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
    val nestedListAdapter = NestedListAdapter()
    val concatAdapter = ConcatAdapter(nestedListAdapter)

    binding.recyclerView.apply {
        adapter = concatAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    }

    viewModel.movies.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { items ->
        nestedListAdapter.clearItems()
        nestedListAdapter.addItems(items)
        nestedListAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, items.size)
    })
}
```

I've also tried to delay binding the adapter to the outer recyclerview:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
    lateinit var concatAdapter: ConcatAdapter()

    binding.recyclerView.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
    }

    viewModel.movies.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { items ->

        concatAdapter = ConcatAdapter(MovieHorizontalListAdapter(it.data.toMutableList()))

        if (binding.recyclerView.adapter != concatAdapter) {
            binding.recyclerView.adapter = concatAdapter
        }

    })
}
```

**My nested Recyclerview Adapter**

```
class NestedListAdapter(
     private val listItems: MutableList<Movie> = mutableListOf()
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NestedListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
private val scrollStates: MutableMap<String, Parcelable?> = mutableMapOf()
private val viewPool = RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool()

init {
    // this does not do anything, (it's also added in the MovieListAdapter)
    stateRestorationPolicy = StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
}

private fun getSectionID(position: Int): String {
    return listItems.getOrNull(position)?.id?.toString().orEmpty()
}

override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder)

    val key = getSectionID(holder.layoutPosition)
    scrollStates[key] = holder.rv.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val binding = NestedListAdapterBinding.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
        parent,
        false
    )

    return ViewHolder(binding)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = if (listItems.isEmpty()) 0 else 1

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(listItems)
}

inner class ViewHolder(
    binding: NestedListAdapterBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    val rv = binding.recyclerView

    fun bind(listItems: List<Movie>) {
        val lm = LinearLayoutManager(rv.context, HORIZONTAL, false)
        lm.initialPrefetchItemCount = 4

        rv.apply {
            setRecycledViewPool(viewPool)
            layoutManager = lm
            adapter = MovieListAdapter(listItems)
        }

        restoreState()
    }

    // This is to restore the state when recycling items (not rotation)
    private fun restoreState() {
        val key = getSectionID(layoutPosition)
        val state = scrollStates[key]
        if (state != null) {
            rv.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(state)
        } else {
            val padding = rv.resources.getDimension(R.dimen.default_padding).toInt()
            rv.addItemDecoration(HorizontalListMarginDecoration(padding))
            rv.layoutManager?.scrollToPosition(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: unfortunately not yet